# How do I get input as array in Python?

Tags: python

I'm  new, learning Python. I don't know how to get input from user as an array. This is my code:

```
test = [0,50,100]
```

In this I have given three inputs by assigning it to test directly.  I need to know how to get the input directly from the user.

Comment: do you know how to get *any* input?

Comment: ^ Same process for any data type. Doesn't have to be numbers.

Comment: Deleted my answer. I misunderstood what you wanted.